Generic TypeScript function returning type of object key
I have the following code structure to manage some settings :
interface Settings {}

interface ServerSettings extends Settings {
    host: string;
    port: number;
    valid: boolean;
}

interface SomeOtherSettings extends Settings {
    enabled: boolean;
}

class SettingsProvider {
    constructor(private settings: Settings) {}

    public get<S extends Settings>(
        key: keyof S,
    ): S[typeof key] {
        return (this.settings as unknown as S)[key];
    }
}

const settings: ServerSettings & SomeOtherSettings = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    valid: true,
    enabled: false,
};
const provider = new SettingsProvider(settings);
const port = provider.get<ServerSettings>('port');


The problem is that the type of port is const port: string | number | boolean (the union of all the possible types of ServerSettings), and not number, as one would expect, given the return type of the function being S[typeof key].
How can I get the right type narrowed ?
One solution could be to pass a second generic to the function like Key extends keyof S but this seems very redundant.

Why do you use generic for the get function? Why not replace S with the actual type of this.settings?

This is not sound. provider.get<{ port: string }>('port') returns incorrect type.

@ouuan I've hardcoded settings in the class for the example, but actually, ServiceProvider is not aware of the actual type of settings. It's injected (IoC) in it. The only thing it knows is that it extends Settings. (I've updated the code snippet to make it clearer).

How does it get "injected" exactly? With the example as given, you need the code to look like this playground link for it to make any sense. If you really want the developer to assert what S is every time they call get() then you're not getting any type safety and you might as well just use any or something and assert the return type. So if you want something actually type safe or close to it, we'll need a [mre] that shows some injection.

(see prev comment). Like, maybe you're doing it like this playground link shows? Not sure. A [mre] would help here.


One solution could be to pass a second generic to the function like Key extends keyof S but this seems very redundant.

This sounds like typescript - Providing only some types for generic type - Stack Overflow.
A workaround is to curry the function:
class SettingsProvider {
    constructor(private settings: Settings) {}

    public get<S extends Settings>() {
        return <K extends keyof S>(key: K) => {
            return (this.settings as S)[key];
        }
    }
}

const settings: ServerSettings & SomeOtherSettings = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    valid: true,
    enabled: false,
};
const provider = new SettingsProvider(settings);

const port = provider.get<ServerSettings>()('port');

const getter = provider.get<ServerSettings>();
const host = getter('host');
const valid = getter('valid');

